# directive template not displaying on view angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want my directive to respond on a DOM element click event,  the directive would call a service which returns a string and then through the template, (company details property on the scope return the string along with the template html.

At the moment, the template is not showing on screen,

**Directive**

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js" />

myAppModule.directive("displayCompanyDetails", function () {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div id='companyDetails' ng-model='companyDetails'></div>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        $('.companyName').bind('click', function (event) {
            scope.companyDetails = scope.GetCompanyDetails(this.id)
        });

    }

}
});
```

**View**

```
    @foreach (var company in Model)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.Label(company.Name, new { @class = "companyName", id = company.Company_Id })
            <p></p>
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div id="companyDetailsDiv" ng-controller="CompanyDetailsCtrl">
    <display-company-details  />
</div>

 getCompanyDetails service method
 GetCompanyDetails: function (customerId) 
 {
     $http.get("http://localhost:61503/Company/CompanyDetails/" +                              
         customerId).success(function (data) 
     {

        }).error(function () 
        {
            alert("an unexpected error has occured")
        });
     }
```

Comment: Does the click event fires?

Comment: can you post a little more of your code, maybe a working (well broken) version on http://plnkr.co/?

Answer (score -1):

This isn't using a directive, but I think this is the type of functionality with a service that you are looking for:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

<div ng:repeat="company in companies" id="companyName" ng-click="getCompanyDetails(company.id);">
    <label><em>Name:</em> {{company.name}}</label>
    <label><em>ID:</em> {{company.id}}</label>
</div>

<hr/>

Address: {{details.address}}<p>
Phone: {{details.phone}}
```

JS:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module("myApp", []);
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope, companyDetailsService) {

    $scope.companies = [
      { name: 'company ABC', id:1},
      { name: 'company 123', id:2},
      { name: 'company XYZ', id:3},
    ];

    $scope.details = {};
    $scope.getCompanyDetails = function (id) {
      $scope.details = companyDetailsService.GetCompanyDetails(id);
    };
});

myAppModule.factory("companyDetailsService", function () {

  return { 
    GetCompanyDetails: function(id) {
      var companies = {
        1: {address:"ABC main", phone:"6785309"},
        2: {address:"123 main", phone:"1234567"},
        3: {address:"XYZ main", phone:"9876543"}
      };
      return companies[id];
    }
  };
});
```

[Full Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tb3ZLt?p=preview).

You may also want to take a look at [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and [this quick tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router) to get the kind of functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up giving up using the directive route and instead called the function in the scope directly. Like above.  Ideally, I would like to have returned a html template, once a company name had been clicked, instead of just the value. I would be interested to see how this, could be done using a directive, and returning a template.